# How to flatten array to its tuple elements -scala

Tags: arrays, scala, tuples

Need help to flatten this...

```
Vector((1,2),(3,4),Array((5,6),(7,8)),(9,10))
```

Expected output

```
Array((1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10))
```

Thank you

Comment: What did you try already? Also, having a mixed collection is probably a "smell" that something is not quite right in the program logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala flatten list of String and List\[String\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40338975/scala-flatten-list-of-string-and-liststring)

Comment: Note that your input, `Vector((1,2),(3,4),Array((5,6),(7,8)),(9,10))` has a type of `Vector[Serializable]`, which may not be very useful.

Answer (score 5):

```
val xx = Vector((1,2),(3,4),Array((5,6),(7,8)),(9,10))
xx.flatten {
  case a: Array[_] => a.toVector
  case t => Vector(t)
}.toArray
```

The code that created a collection of that type needs to be thrown out.

Comment: Aside - see why such a solution, i.e. run-time checking `xx`'s element isn't possible in Haskell - http://cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/05-type-classes.html.