# Scala append or concat to list depending on type

Tags: java, scala, list

Let say I have a List[Int] a, b and Int c:

```
val a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
val b: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)
val c: Int = 7

val d: List[Int] = a ++ b
val e: List[Int] = a :+ c
```

In both `d` and `e`, we get the same output. But we need different operators.

My question is: is there any operator or a function that takes in a list and a object, and concats with the object is a list of the same type and appends if the object can be a member of the list.

Comment: Do you have an usecase? It would seem that the codepath leading to such requirement needs review.

Comment: Why not have two separate overloads? One taking a `List[T]` and one taking a `T`?

Comment: Note that appending to a list (`:+`) has a complexity of _O(n)_. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7794338/6231376) for more info.

Comment: Given an arbitrarily nested list of Int, I want to be able to flatten it to one list of Int.

Comment: @VarunPatro note that all elements of the (homogeneous) `List` have to be of the same type, so you can't have "arbitrarily nested list of Int", either list of `Int`s, or a list of lists of `Int`s: `List[List[Int]]`, etc. but not a list with varying nestedness.

Comment: @VarunPatro also you say "In both d and e, we get the same output", but it's not true. Do you mean the same type or what?

Comment: Related questions: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32735304/736957), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27679741/736957), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1737452/736957)